# query expressions issue in Join()

Tags: linq, query-expressions

I am having a issue when writing a below expression

```
var contactDetails = context.contacts
                            .Where(s=>s.contact_code == contactCode)
                            .Join(context.accounts, s => s.)
```

It will not list down the properties after "."

Any Idea? I have import the using System.Linq too.

Comment: If you have not added using System; then intellisense may not show you the properties

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactDetails =  (from con in context.contacts.Where(s=>s.contact_code == contactCode)
                      join acc in context.accounts
                      on con.Property equals acc.Property
                      select con or select acc or select new{con,acc})
```

`select con` if you only want `contacts`
`select acc` if you only want `accounts`
`select new{con,acc}` if you only want both

**Note** use only one `select`

Comment: I want to do something like this without using from keyword 

 var questionList1 = context.QuizConfiguration.Where(qc => qc.RoundId == roundId).
                    Join(context.Question, qc => qc.QuestionId, q => q.QuestionId, (qc, q) => new { qc, q }).
                    Join(context.Answer, q => q.q.QuestionId, ans => ans.QuestionId, (q, ans) => new { q, ans }).ToList();

Comment: @Dinesh the snippet you have writtern should word...did it not?